# js.erb not rendered - ActionView::MissingTemplate

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a view file named feed.js.erb which is located in app/views/sports/feed.js.erb containing:

```
<% if @newsfeed.nil? %>   
    alert("No news items for #{@athlete.nil? ? @team : @athlete.full_name}!")  
<% else %>   
    $("#sportfeed").append("<%= j render 'newsfeeds/newsfeed', feed: @newsfeed %>");  
<% end %>
```

Controller action in SportsController is

```
def feed  
  if params[:sport]  
      @newsfeed = get_sport_news(Sport.find(params[:sport]))  
  elsif params[:athlete]  
      @athlete = params[:athlete]  
      @newsfeed = get_athlete_news(Athlete.find(params[:athlete]))  
  elsif params[:team]  
      @team = params[:team]  
      @newsfeed = get_team_news(@sport.id, params[:team])  
  end  
end
```

routes in routes.rb are:

```
resources :sports do  
  collection do  
      get :feed  
  end  
end
```

What I am getting is

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template sports/feed, application/feed with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}
```

This is strange since I have successfully rendered js.erb from create via another controller. I know this is something simple but I cannot seem to crack it. Very frustrating. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
```

or even

```
render :template => 'sports/feed'
```

Within your success if statement block? This forces the controller to format the js.erb